# php blowfish hashing with crypt(): the CLI result differs from webserver's one

Tags: php, blowfish, crypt

When I use php function crypt() using Blowfish algorithm **with web-server**:

```
<?php

    echo crypt('SAD123', sprintf('$2a$10$%s', '7711cbpe58dfpogiu049857f011werb0'));
```

I get this result:

```
$2a$10$7711cbpe58dfpogiu0498u5Vh773A3qx.3LE3ro3NX7F9c9N7.pOm
```

But if I'm using PHP interpretor **with command line**:

```
php -r "echo crypt('SAD123', sprintf('$2a$10$%s', '7711cbpe58dfpogiu049857f011werb0'));"
```

I'm getting another result:

```
a0SqNHxQ8/2mA
```

Do you have any ideas?

The system is:
Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS),
PHP Version 5.4.26

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the dollar-signs with the following digits in your command-string are also interpreted as [positional parameters](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/posparams) in bash.

When you escape them, it will work as expected:

```
$ php -r "echo crypt('SAD123', sprintf('\$2a\$10$%s', '7711cbpe58dfpogiu049857f011werb0'));"
```

So when you want to tinker with some PHP in your comman line, you should just run it interactively:

```
$ php -a
php > echo crypt('SAD123', sprintf('$2a$10$%s', '7711cbpe58dfpogiu049857f011werb0'));
```